# passing id through the URL grails groovy

Tags: grails

I'm writing a grails application, where I have `region`, `district` and `streams`. `region` contains `district`, so `region_id` is a `foreign key` for the `district` table. In other to query only rows associated with that `region`, I need to be able to pass the `id` to the URL.
Here is my `UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(controller:"/user")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
```

However, then I go to the link I created to forward to the `district` controller (default is `list` I see:
`localhost:8080/project/district/list`, but it does not have the `region_id`, so I was expecting `localhost:8080/project/district/list/region_id='1'?` or `localhost:8080/project/district/list/id='1'?`
Could someone please help me pointing out where is my mistake?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/$controller/$action?/$id?` means that `params` maps will have property `id` with value from url. For url like `/project/district/list/5` this map returns 5 (`assert params.id == 5`).

Also you can call your action by using following url: `/project/district/list?region_id=5` and get 5 for `params.region_id`.

If you want to have different name, `region_id` instead of `id, and don't want to pass it as a query parameter, you can make your own mapping:

```
"/district/list/$region_id"(controller:"district", action: "list")
```

At this case this url is mapped strictly to controller `district` and action `list` and `params.region_id` will return 5 for `/project/district/list/5`